# Property level permission on REST APIs responses [ Java ]

Tags: java, spring, backend

If I've a bean class that represents a table and it's data returns as a response of an API. That API is called from multiple clients with multiple roles and features that limits the properties visibility. I'm asking about a way or framework that handle that scenario dynamically.
For example:
- We have a user table:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  f_name  |  l_name  | mobile  |  email    | birth_date  |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  12  |  Ahmed   |  Adel    | 123456  |  a@a.com  | 01/02/90    |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- We have a bean that represents that row:

```
class User {
  private int id;
  private String fName;
  private String lName;
  private String mobile;
  private String email;
  private String bDate;
.
.
}
```

So in an API like:

......../....../user/12

The JSON response could be:

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "fName": "Ahmed",
  "lName": "Adel",
  "mobile": "123456",
  "email": "a@a.com",
  "bDate": "01/02/90"
}
```

**what is needed is,**

* If the client is a normal user then he should be forced get just the below response:

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "fName": "Ahmed",
  "lName": "Adel",
  "mobile": null,
  "email": null,
  "bDate": null
}
```

* If the client is a higher level user then he can get more details as the below response:

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "fName": "Ahmed",
  "lName": "Adel",
  "mobile": "123456",
  "email": "a@a.com",
  "bDate": null
}
```

* If the client is an admin then he can get full details as the below response:

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "fName": "Ahmed",
  "lName": "Adel",
  "mobile": "123456",
  "email": "a@a.com",
  "bDate": "01/02/90"
}
```

Comment: Do you use Spring Security? In your Endpoint Resources you could basically query the Role of the current user and act accordingly.

Comment: But that mean I should do a response scenario for every role. I'm trying to find something dynamic.

Comment: Have you looked into an API Manager?

Comment: No, could you please recommend one?

Comment: There are a lot out there. To mention one, apiman.io.

Comment: Why don't you expose DB connections to the clients directly? Would be way more performant then the constant marshalling back and forth to JSON and mimicking what SQL already provides for decates, table-views and user-permissions. Further, REST is not about exposing DB models via HTTP APIs but to implement a way to decouple clients from servers/APIs. This requires dedicated steps that all need to be applied fully as otherwise a coupling will remain making all the work useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try jsonView @JsonView
Here is how you can apply it 
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to do it would be with `@JsonView` jackson annotation.

Define the views:

```
public class UserViews {
    public static class Normal {}
    public static class High extends Normal {}
    public static class Admin extends High {}
}
```

Annotate your model:

```
class User {
    @JsonView(UserViews.Normal.class)
    private int id;
    @JsonView(UserViews.Normal.class)
    private String fName;
    @JsonView(UserViews.Normal.class)
    private String lName;
    @JsonView(UserViews.High.class)
    private String mobile;
    @JsonView(UserViews.High.class)
    private String email;
    @JsonView(UserViews.Admin.class)
    private String bDate;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And tell jackson which view should use to serialize:

```
mapper.writerWithView(UserViews.Admin.class).writeValueAsString(user);
```

You could encapsulate and centralize the logic of which view jackson should use before sending the data to frontend.